# Who deletes my comments and why?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed recently that a number of my comments on various questions and answers were deleted. The most recent example is my comment on [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/174069/why-the-term-relational).

The comment contained a quote from Wikipedia and a link to the article there, explicitly answering the question. It was too short to be posted as a full-fledged answer but nevertheless answered the question.

After a couple of days my and few other comments have been deleted, I presume by a moderator. Is there any explanation as to why someone deems it appropriate to censor communications on this site?

Comment: The short answer is: **Paul** ;)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ thank you for your prompt response

Answer (score 11):

The general reasoning can be found in the meta Q & A [How can comments disappear?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1328/how-can-comments-disappear)

> The comment contained a quote from Wikipedia and a link to the article there, explicitly answering the question. It was too short to be posted as a full-fledged answer but nevertheless answered the question.

There is explicit guidance in the comment box, on the "add a comment" tooltip, and in the [Help Centre](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) to **not post answers in comments**.

[image: Tooltip]

[image: Comment box]

In this specific instance, the comment you left was also *obsolete* as soon as one of the [*answers*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/174074/1192) included the same (or very similar) information. Your comment did not include a link.

[image: deleted comments]

If you want to *answer* a question, please do so using the *answer box*. If you don't have time to write a full answer that meets your own quality standards, consider contributing what you can as a [Community Wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) so it is easier for other people to improve your contribution.

Or simply move on to another question you are able to write a proper answer for. As that question shows, other users will be along to write a great answer sooner or later regardless.